# How to analyze position score in Stockfish

Tags: chess, uci, fen

I have a [FEN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation) position and I want to analyze which position is stronger. 
For example,  I have this position

```
rnbq1bnr/pp2k2N/8/2p1p2Q/4N3/8/PPPP1PPP/R1B1KB1R b KQ - 0 1
```

How to evaluate a position and get score value using [Stockfish](https://stockfishchess.org/)? (example, the white score is +9 or black -5)

Comment: Are you asking about linking to SF automatically from your program?

Comment: Please see the screenshot( https://prnt.sc/qo4737 ), for example for this position Stockfish calculates that white position is stronger and score is +9.6

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/q/50116972/4748017

Comment: No, I already have FEN, just I need to calculate with Stockfish which position is stronger

Comment: I have a similar question, but I'm trying to do it in R or the CLI: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74904491/9727624

Answer (score 4):

With Python you could use the [python-chess](https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library:

```python
import chess
import chess.engine

engine = chess.engine.SimpleEngine.popen_uci("stockfish")

board = chess.Board("rnbq1bnr/pp2k2N/8/2p1p2Q/4N3/8/PPPP1PPP/R1B1KB1R b KQ - 0 1")
info = engine.analyse(board, chess.engine.Limit(depth=20))
print("Score:", info["score"])
# Score: #+9

engine.quit()
```

Take a look at the [engine module](https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/engine.html) for further details.